# read user info from FirebaseFirestore in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to read document info from Database this my code

```
abstract class Database{
  Future<void> sendText(SendOrder textData);
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> readDataStream();
}
class FirestoreDatabase implements Database{
  FirestoreDatabase({required this.uid});
  final String uid;

  @override
  Future<void> sendText(SendOrder textData) async {
    final documentRefer = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userInfo').doc(uid);
    await documentRefer.set(textData.toMap());
  }


  @override
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> readDataStream() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userInfo').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();
  }

}
```

with send text I got no problem but read data I got problem

```
getData() async{
  return database.readDataStream().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs);
}

Future<void> _dataSend(BuildContext context) async {
  await database.sendText(SendOrder(userName: 'name', coins: '12', level: '12'));
}
```

```
body: StreamBuilder<Database>(
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
          _dataSend(context);
        }, child:
        const Text('Click')),

        Text(
    getData().toString()
     , style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        )
      ],
    );
  },
)
```

I need to read map data but I have problem becuase I'm new flutter developer , don't know how to convert data or where comes from
so how to read data?

Is my code right to read as StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

You had not set `stream` for your `StreamBuilder`. Check below code for simple  StreamBuilder:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Stream<String> _generateNumbers() async* {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield "$i";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<String>(
          stream: _generateNumbers(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active
                || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Text('Error');
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(
                    snapshot.data ?? '',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40)
                );
              } else {
                return const Text('Empty data');
              }
            } else {
              return Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```